# Ontology mapping & alignment

Tags: mapping, alignment, ontology

Ontology mapping and alignment is still a fresh research area. It is used to combine two or more ontologies (like owl or owl2) into one file called an alignment. 
Anyone have any idea or algorithm to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Usually, the people involved in this domain of research use the word alignment to desribe the correspondences that exist between ontologies, not the combination of the two ontologies in one, which is usually called the merge of the two ontologies.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, or your workplace can buy it, get the book "Ontology Matching", by Jérôme Euzenat and Pavel Shvaiko. It contains descriptions of techniques, algorithms, tools and references. The authors are working on a new updated edition, by the way, so if you can wait a bit, buy the newer edition.

If you want to get deeper in the topic and you are extremely motivated, you can take a look at the list of [~700+ references to academic publications on the topic of ontology matching](http://www.ontologymatching.org/publications.html) on the web site www.ontologymatching.org.

Answer (score 0):

What do you know already? What have you investigated?

have you seen - http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/silk/ - full framework dedicated to generating linkages between ontologies.

also see - http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/

Theres concepts of terms semantic similarity - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Google_distance, wordnet similarity.

You could also investigate methods that utilise thesauri eg. umls (in the medical field), wikipedia page redirects more generally.

Comment: Although you can use SILK for ontology matching, SILK is normally intended for the matching of instances. But SILK is in fact a language to specify alignments rather than an algorithm for aligning.